# What is inheriting in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I'm following a tutorial and I didn't understand what I am supposed to do:

> create a new Cocoa Touch class. Name it “AddCommentsViewController”, make it inherit from “UIViewController”

I don't know and don't understand `inheriting`

Comment: Inheritence is a fundamental concept of `object oriented programming`, `Swift` happens to be one of many `object oriented programming` languages.

Comment: There is a chapter about "Inheritance" in the Swift language reference. You are supposed to define a *subclass* of UIViewController.

Comment: Maybe you should try to google it first

Comment: Interesting that you tagged the question with [tag:inheritance] - the tag description tells you the answer :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

goto 
File > New > File or use shortcut key (COMMAND+N)

[Select Cocoa Touch Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4hJj.png)

[Enter Class Name **AddCommentsViewController**
Select Subclass of **UIViewController**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuyqc.png)

Press Next and then press create.

A new Cocoa Touch class named **AddCommentsViewController** is created inherit from **UIViewController**

Answer (score -2):

It means you have to make a new class which will inherit from `UIViewController`.
This is a basic concept of object oriented programming which C++, Java, Javascript, Swift, Objective-C, C#, and other modern languages are based on.

An inherited class is called a subclass of its parent class. It will inherit all the properties and methods of the parent class.

I your case, what the tutorial is instructing you to do is to go to File > New > File....
Select Cocoa Touch class.
Name it "AddCommentsViewController" and select `UIViewController` from the dropdown below and next and create.